# Symfony 1.4 - format_currency API

Tags: symfony-1.4

So I am working with some numbers which are to be formatted with user's preferred currency format, but ran into a huge wtf and wanted to see how other symfonians handled the sitch.

Using the `NumberFormatter` helper there is a `format_currency` function I can call which looks like this:

```
function format_currency($amount, $currency = null, $culture = null)
{
  if (null === $amount)
  {
    return null;
  }

  $numberFormat = new sfNumberFormat(_current_language($culture));

  return $numberFormat->format($amount, 'c', $currency);
}
```

And the signature of `sfNumberFormat::format` looks like:

```
function format($number, $pattern = 'd', $currency = 'USD', $charset = 'UTF-8')
```

See the problem? The `format_currency` signature allows a default null currency value if no currency value is passed, which then overrides the default currency value of the `sfNumberFormat::format` signature.

My goals here are to set the user's preferred currency once, and only have to pass the number to the `format_currency` function, as it makes 0 sense to pass in the currency value for X number of calls.

What I am thinking, is adding a new user attribute which will store the user's preferred currency, then copying the NumberFormat code into my own lib/helper and referencing the user's attribute to be passed into the `sfNumberFormat::format` call.

Any symfonian solve this another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up just copying and pasting the source NumberHelper functions into my own lib/helper/NumberHelper.php and changed the signature of `currency_helper` like this:

```
// Before
function format_currency($amount, $currency = null, $culture = null)

// After
function format_currency($amount, $currency = 'USD', $culture = null)
```

This allows $currency to pass through to `sfNumberFormat::format` with the same value (usd), vs passing null.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you can pass the currency to every call to the helper is that you can have multiple currencies used for one user, regardless of his/her culture settings.

I also don't see a problem in passing the currency to the each helper call.

In fact if you create a helper which will rely on a session attribute you will make a strong coupling between the user object and the helper, which I don't thing is right. How do you plan to retrieve the attribute inside the helper? You will either have to call `sfContext::get` (which should generally be avoided) or pass the user object to the helper (which is exactly the same as passing the attribute, or even worse ;) ).

Comment: Good observation about tightly coupling the currency to the user, however, the culture is coupled to the user so coupling currency wouldn't be that big of a stretch. That way I could default to user default currency, but still have ability to pass in any other currency type as an arg. But to be honest, I think the easiest change would be to change the `$currency = null` to `$currency = 'USD'` in the `format_currency` signature, that way it will be a straight pass through.

Comment: True - that will be the easiest :) As for the coupling - the idea is to keep the classes detached, no matter how easy or hard this is ;) In fact the culture is the attribute of the user class, so it's hard to be pointing to a strong or weak coupling between those two. :) And again - remember that in fact the currency does not have to be dependant on the user's culture. Think of a website were you can change the language but keep the prices in the same currency, or where you can change currency and language independently (which I think is quite common in web shops).

Comment: Right, I get how coupling works, but symfony has already coupled culture to the user for language etc with the assumption that the site will be rendered in the user's preferred language. The same principle can be applied to currency. Sure there may be instances where you want to show currencies outside of the user's preference, but 95% of the time it will be based on user preference. My issue is that Symfony considered language, but not currency format.